# Layout specific to HTTPS

Tags: layout, https

I am wondering if there is a way to customize the layout for when you are on a https page. As in creating a entire layout file or just layout statements in existing files that will only activate on https pages.

I recently ran into some problems with sharethis where I was including the non-https version that worked until we activated https urls on the site. After this the script was being blocked as it was a non-https url.

The solution that I found for this was to switch to the share this secure url which works for both. However it got me thinking if there was a way to use layouts to fix problems similar to this.

I have found you can simply use "//www.example.com" to automatically pull the current http/https however this doesn't work for different urls like share this.

http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js

https://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js

For example if you wanted to add a block advertising your sever security only when you are in https. Would this need to be done in a php block or could it be done via xml layouts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this case, we can add new  layout handler on basic of `http/https` at event `controller_action_layout_load_before`.

**Event:** `controller_action_layout_load_before`

**Condition:**  `Mage::app()->getRequest()->isSecure()`  is check page with `https or http`.

So , i am start an observer on basic of this condition which is add new
handler on current layout

When page with

- `https` then add handler `my_current_page_is_https`
- `http` then add handler `my_current_page_is_http`

**Observer code:**

```
<?php
class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Observe{ 
/**
     * Before load layout event handler
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function beforeLoadLayout($observer)
    {
        $isSecure =  Mage::app()->getRequest()->isSecure();

        $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate()
           ->addHandle('my_current_page_is_' . ($isSecure ? 'https' : 'http'));
    }


}
```

**Config.xml code;**

```
<global>
    <models>
        <[MyCustomModule_Model_Class_Groupname]>
            <class>[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model</class>
        </[MyCustomModule_Model_Class_Groupname]>
    </models>
</global>
   <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <my_current_page_is_observer>
                        <class>[MyCustomModule_Model_Class_Groupname]/observer</class>
                        <method>beforeLoadLayout</method>
                    </my_current_page_is_observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
     </events>
   </frontend>
```

**Now on this of this handler,you can add a new block to layout  and a new phtml.**

Suppose, you want to change the layout all `https page to 1-column` then you can try this.

```
<my_current_page_is_https>
    <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
            <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
            <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
            <action method="setLayoutCode"><name>one_column</name></action>
        </reference>
</my_current_page_is_https>
```